# How to split existing buffer vertically in vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I have list of buffers in vim. I can split buffer horizontally using :sb[N] where N is the buffer number. How can I split the buffer vertically ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The `vs` and `vsplit` commands take a filename as an argument like `:vs somefile` to open a file in a vertical split.

To put an existing buffer in a split window you use the `sb#` command (where # is the buffer number). Splits in VIM default to horizontal, to change this, prefix your command with `vert` which forces a vertical split of the next split command.

`:vert sb#`

**Where # is the buffer number**

Comment: I know :vsplit. I doesn't seem to take buffer number.

Comment: I thought it was to easy :P .. try
:vert sbN -where N is the buffer number

Comment: wohoo! It works.

Comment: @blacklife: so the answer is actually ":vert sbN" ?

Comment: Since `:sb` works with buffer names too, this will also works with buffer names: `:vert sb vimrc`

Comment: @blacklife `:vsplit %`

Answer (score 2):

This is a command I created and added to my .vimrc to allow me to open a current buffer in a vertical split

```
command -nargs=1 Vsb call VsbFunction(<f-args>)

function VsbFunction (arg1)
  execute 'vert sb' a:arg1
endfunction
```

Comment: you mean open all files currently in the buffer on vertical splits right? that was the answer i was looking for.

Comment: How am I supposed to execute this?

Comment: `:Vsb somefile`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vim-fzf` plugins and:

> Similarly to {ctrlp.vim}{3}, use enter key, CTRL-T, CTRL-X or CTRL-V to open
> selected files in the current window, in new tabs, in horizontal splits, or in
> vertical splits respectively.

use `:Buffers` select and hit `CTRL-V`

Answer (score 0):

As *kirysu* said, but additionally with "positioning the other split".

```
:vert rightbelow sb otherfile.txt
```

or

```
:vert bel sb otherfile.txt
```

... opens a existing buffer, named `otherfile.txt`, in a split "***right below***" the existing one.
In the case of vertical splitting, it means "*right side of the existing buffer*".

Here you can use the `[tab]`-key too, to let vim complete the buffer-name!

(see `:help :vert` too, for further "positioning"-commands)